# Inserting a string into a list without getting split into characters

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and can't find a way to insert a string into a list without it getting split into individual characters:

```
>>> list=['hello','world']
>>> list
['hello', 'world']
>>> list[:0]='foo'
>>> list
['f', 'o', 'o', 'hello', 'world']
```

What should I do to have:

```
['foo', 'hello', 'world']
```

Searched the docs and the Web, but it has not been my day.

Comment: The linked question is newer than this one. Why then is this question closed as a duplicate of the newer question?

Comment: Age is not a deciding factor in deciding which direction to close. The other question and its answers have been better received, and thus is generally considered the better close target.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

To add to the end of the list:

```
list.append('foo')
```

To insert at the beginning:

```
list.insert(0, 'foo')
```

Comment: I'm sure most people know this but just to add: doing `list2 = list1.append('foo')` or `list2 = list1.insert(0, 'foo')`  will result in `list2` having a value of None. Both `append` and `insert` are methods that mutate the list they are used on rather than returning a new list.

Answer (score 23):

Sticking to the method you are using to insert it, use

```
list[:0] = ['foo']
```

http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Comment: This slice assignment insertion is faster than Raffe Kettler's list.insert(). See [Append a column to a 2 dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537417/append-a-column-to-a-2-dimensional-array). Not that it usually matters.

Answer (score 16):

Another option is using the overloaded `+ operator`:

```
>>> l = ['hello','world']
>>> l = ['foo'] + l
>>> l
['foo', 'hello', 'world']
```

Comment: Just seen you can also use it to append at the end:
    `l += ['foo']`

Answer (score 10):

best put brackets around foo, and use +=

```
list+=['foo']
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> li = ['aaa', 'bbb']
>>> li.insert(0, 'wow!')
>>> li
['wow!', 'aaa', 'bbb']
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use list as a variable name. It's a built in that you are masking.

To insert, use the insert function of lists.

```
l = ['hello','world']
l.insert(0, 'foo')
print l
['foo', 'hello', 'world']
```

Comment: This isn't quite correct. `insert()` takes a second argument.

Comment: @RafeKettler Whoops, append is the one without a place argument.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add another list:

```
list[:0]=['foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
ls=['hello','world']
ls.append('python')
['hello', 'world', 'python']
```

or (use `insert` function where you can use index position in list)

```py
ls.insert(0,'python')
print(ls)
['python', 'hello', 'world']
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to add the '+' operator as follows:

list = list + ['foo']

Hope it helps!