# Append a column to a 2 dimensional array

Tags: python

I have a 2d array in Python called "AllLines"

```
[['Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'], 
 ['Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n'], 
 ['Dell Computers', '9000', '2\n'], 
 ['HBC Corp', '9000', '3\n'], 
 ['HBC INC', '9000', '4']]
```

So, it is an array within an array. I need to append items to the inside array. To give me this:

```
[['NEW','Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'], 
 ['N-E-W','Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n'], 
 ['N-E-W---','Dell Computers', '9000', '2\n'], 
 ['N-E---W','HBC Corp', '9000', '3\n'], 
 ['N-W-W','HBC INC', '9000', '4']]
```

How do I achieve adding a new item to the inside arrays?

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on each of your 2D arrays.

Comment: Thank you, that was just the output if I print the array, it wasn't code. The array itself works, I tested it. I just need to append items to the inside array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a slice assignment:

```
>>> a = [['Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'], ['Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n']]
>>> a[0][0:0] = ["NEW"]
>>> a[1][0:0] = ["N-E-W"]
>>> a
[['NEW', 'Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'], ['N-E-W', 'Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n']]
```

Some timings:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="a = [['Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field'], ['Dell Inc', '9000', '1']]", 
    stmt="a[0][0:0] = ['NEW']", number=100000)
3.57850867468278
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="a = [['Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field'], ['Dell Inc', '9000', '1']]", 
    stmt="a[0].insert(0, 'NEW')", number=100000)
4.941971139085055
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="a = [['Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field'], ['Dell Inc', '9000', '1']]", 
    stmt="a[0] = ['NEW'] + a[0]", number=100000)
33.147023662906804
```

Comment: I never thought of using slicing like that to insert a single item.  I wonder if there are any benefits/drawbacks compared to `list.insert` ...

Comment: @mgilson: It's measurably faster.

Comment: Really?  I would expect it to be equal or slower since `insert` is a more constrained case.  Very weird.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Great solution, Tim. Thanks to everyone that took the time to answer.

Comment: For the record, the timings were done on Python 3.2.3, 64 bit (Win 7). @mgilson found similar results on Python 2.7 on OSX 10.5.8. Check out his excellent follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537716/why-is-slice-assignment-faster-than-list-insert).

Answer (score 5):

You can append or insert into them just as you would any other list e.g:

```
lst = list_of_lists[0]
lst.insert(0,'NEW')
```

Or, in one line:

```
list_of_lists[0].insert(0,'NEW')
```

Comment: I think this solution adds an item to the outside array. I need this item added to the inside array. >>> a[0][0:0] = ["NEW"]
>>> a[1][0:0] = ["N-E-W"]
seems to work

Comment: @fredykruger -- Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: @fredykruger -- This should do the same thing.  `a[0].insert(0,'NEW')`

Answer (score 2):

```
AllLines = [['Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'], ['Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n'], ['Dell Computers', '9000', '2\n'], ['HBC Corp', '9000', '3\n'], ['HBC INC', '9000', '4']
```

To add "NEW" to the beginning of each row:

```
newAllLines = [['NEW']+row for row in AllLines]
```

If you have a list called `firsts` of items such that the `i`th item of `firsts` must be added as the first column of the `i`th row, then:

```
newAllLines = [list(i[0])+i[1] for i in zip(firsts, AllLines)]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: List concatenation using `+` is very slow. See the timings in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lis=[['Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'], ['Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n'], ['Dell Computers', '9000', '2\n'], ['HBC Corp', '9000', '3\n'], ['HBC INC', '9000', '4']]
>>> lis1=['NEW','N-E-W','N-E-W---','N-E---W','N-W-W']
>>> for i,x in enumerate(lis1):
    lis[i].insert(0,x)


>>> lis
[['NEW', 'Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'], ['N-E-W', 'Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n'], ['N-E-W---', 'Dell Computers', '9000', '2\n'], ['N-E---W', 'HBC Corp', '9000', '3\n'], ['N-W-W', 'HBC INC', '9000', '4']]
```

or as @mgilson suggested:

```
for item,lst in zip(lis1,lis): 
    lst.insert(0,item)
```

Comment: In this case, I might do `for item,lst in zip(lis1,lis): lst.insert(0,item)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d=[['Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'],
...  ['Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n'],
...  ['Dell Computers', '9000', '2\n'],
...  ['HBC Corp', '9000', '3\n'],
...  ['HBC INC', '9000', '4']]
>>> d2 = zip(*d)
>>> d2.append([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> print zip(*d2)
[('Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n', 1), ('Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n', 2), ('De
ll Computers', '9000', '2\n', 3), ('HBC Corp', '9000', '3\n', 4), ('HBC INC', '9
000', '4', 5)]
```

or you could shorten it

```
print zip(*(zip(*d)+[[1,2,3,4,5]]))
```

Comment: This answer relies on `zip` returning a `list`, which goes away in `py3k`.

Comment: zip does or just the list (tuple instead?)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [33]: lol = [['Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'], 
 ['Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n'], 
 ['Dell Computers', '9000', '2\n'], 
 ['HBC Corp', '9000', '3\n'], 
 ['HBC INC', '9000', '4']]

In [34]: [line.insert(0, "NEW") for line in lol]


In [35]: lol
Out[35]: 
[['NEW', 'Suppliers', 'Spend', 'Test Field\n'],
 ['NEW', 'Dell Inc', '9000', '1\n'],
 ['NEW', 'Dell Computers', '9000', '2\n'],
 ['NEW', 'HBC Corp', '9000', '3\n'],
 ['NEW', 'HBC INC', '9000', '4']]
```

Comment: Yuck.  Don't use a list-comp for side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the array.

```
array = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
         [6, 7, 8, 9],
         [11, 12, 13, 14],
         [16, 17, 18, 19]]

array = zip(*array)
array[0:0] = [["0", "5", "10", "15"]]
array = zip(*array)
```