# Why is slice assignment faster than `list.insert`?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, python-internals

Inspired by [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12537489/748858),

Here's a benchmark:

```
import timeit

def test1():
    a = [1,2,3]
    a.insert(0,1)

def test2():
    a = [1,2,3]
    a[0:0]=[1]

print (timeit.timeit('test1()','from __main__ import test1'))
print (timeit.timeit('test2()','from __main__ import test2'))
```

For me, `test2` is sligtly faster (~10%).  Why is that the case?  I would expect it to be slower since:

1. slice assignment must be able to accept iterables of any length and therefore must be more general.
2. in slice assignment, we need to create a new list on the right hand side just to get it to work.

Can anybody help me understand this?

*(using python 2.7 on OS-X 10.5.8)*

Comment: Good question :) I'm curious about this myself.

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- your benchmark really threw me for a loop.  I had to test it myself :).

Comment: My guess would be `insert` is implemented by calling the slice assignment code.

Comment: @KeithRandall -- that's actually a reasonable guess (seems like something I would do).  But I wouldn't expect that to make a 10% difference as it could make that call in C, so it would be more or less free (I'd think)...

Comment: have you tested with larger lists (a big range?)

Comment: @KeithRandall: No, the two codepaths are separate (`list_ass_slice` vs. `ins1` in http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bfdf366a779a/Objects/listobject.c).

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- In my benchmark, the list doesn't grow.  But in Tim Pietzcker's (see the linked answer), it grows while benchmarking. (up to a length of around 100000 I think)

Comment: On my Ubuntu box, Python 2.7.3 `test2` is usually faster. However, having run OP's code several times, cc. third of the times `test1` was faster. So this may not be a robust test.

Comment: In Pydroid3 in Andoid with Python 3.11, I get faster results consistently with list.insert than I do with slice assignment.

Comment: Here are my results: ``0.9066034620045684``
``1.4460302309889812``

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink -- yeah, I've just played around with the code on python3.10 and python3.8 -- both are faster using `.insert`.  And -- possibly interestingly -- 3.10 is consistently faster than the 3.8 version.

Comment: It may be due (in my Python) to the curious choice of BUILD_SLICE in slice assignment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your first test case has to call the method `insert` on the list `a`, whereas all the operations in `test2` are handled directly in byte code. Note the `CALL_FUNCTION` in the disassembly of `test1` below. Calling functions is moderately expensive in Python: certainly expensive enough to account for a few percent difference in run time.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              9 BUILD_LIST               3
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          15 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             18 LOAD_ATTR                0 (insert)
             21 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             24 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             30 POP_TOP             
             31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(test2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
              9 BUILD_LIST               3
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3          15 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             18 BUILD_LIST               1
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             24 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             27 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             30 STORE_SLICE+3       
             31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

#### Bad explanation

I posted this first, but after consideration I think it is not correct. The difference I describe here should only make a noticeable difference when there is a lot of data to be moved, which isn't the case in the test here. And even with a lot of data the difference is only a couple of percent:

```
import timeit

def test1():
    a = range(10000000)
    a.insert(1,1)

def test2():
    a = range(10000000)
    a[1:1]=[1]

>>> timeit.timeit(test1, number=10)
6.008707046508789
>>> timeit.timeit(test2, number=10)
5.861173868179321
```

The method `list.insert` is implemented by the function [`ins1`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3e677956eef4/Objects/listobject.c#l239) in `listobject.c`. You'll see that it copies the item references for the tail of the list one by one:

```
for (i = n; --i >= where; )
    items[i+1] = items[i];
```

On the other hand slice assignment is implemented by the function [`list_ass_slice`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3e677956eef4/Objects/listobject.c#l578), which calls `memmove`:

```
memmove(&item[ihigh+d], &item[ihigh],
        (k - ihigh)*sizeof(PyObject *));
```

So I think the answer to your question is that the C library function `memmove` is better optimized than the simple loop. See [here for the glibc implementation of `memmove`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/memmove.c;h=ede27ffcf2cf4f70e7dc259a754abf5f37550f08;hb=HEAD): I believe that when called from `list_ass_slice` it eventually ends up calling [`_wordcopy_bwd_aligned`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/wordcopy.c;h=b171f27c65388f1f629a42d05a8cd1c80e2cf286;hb=HEAD#l219) which you can see is heavily hand-optimized.

Comment: My hunch was that `test1` is slower because of attribute lookup and bound method creation for each `a.insert`. To test this, I defined `test1` as `def test1(ins=list.insert)`, and replaced `a.insert(0, 1)` with `ins(a, 0, 1)` — with almost no measurable difference. :)

Comment: I'm not convinced by your new addition ... doesn't `a[0:0]` implicitly need to call `__setitem__` (via `STORE_SLICE`) since python has no way of knowing that `a` is a list and not some other type?  (correct me if I'm wrong ... I'm not an expert at reading `dis.dis` output).  How is calling `__setitem__` really any different than calling `insert`?  If anything, `setitem` needs to construct an additional `slice` object which then gets interpreted ...

Comment: @user4815162342 -- Doesn't it need to do attribute lookup for `a[0:0]` implicitly as well?  (How does it get access to `__setitem__`?)

Comment: It doesn't — access to `__setitem__` (and many other special methods) is [cached in a member](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#tp_as_sequence) of the C struct that implements the type object. It is accessed with a simple pointer dereference.