# Why is copying a list using a slice[:] faster than using the obvious way?

Tags: python, performance, list, cpython, shallow-copy

Why is shallow-copying a list using a slice so much faster than using `list` builtin?

```
In [1]: x = range(10)

In [2]: timeit x_ = x[:]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 83.2 ns per loop

In [3]: timeit x_ = list(x)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 147 ns per loop
```

Usually when I see weird things like this, they're fixed in python3 - but this discrepancy is still there:

```
In [1]: x = list(range(10))

In [2]: timeit x_ = x[:]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 100 ns per loop

In [3]: timeit x_ = list(x)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 178 ns per loop
```

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537716/why-is-slice-assignment-faster-than-list-insert?rq=1

Comment: one explanation is that `list` is a function that you need to call.

Comment: also list needs to do stuff with each item , where a slice is just copying a block of memory to a new address ...

Comment: Indeed, at least for the case of ``[:]`` it's possible there is an optimization to just do ``memcopy`` on the list, where as I imagine the ``list(x)`` method cannot perform the same optimization, at least not until it's done a lot of other boilerplate stuff that a constructor that has to accept many types has to do. This is pure speculation without having dug into the source though.

Comment: @aruisdante The list constructor certainly first has to check for `PyList_CheckExact`, but this is just pointer arithmetic and a C-level branch (= a few dozen cycles at worst), so I don't think it'll be a significant factor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is in additional function call (just `SLICE+0` vs `CALL_FUNCTION 1` with **extra stack operations**):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(lst):
...  return lst[:]
... 
>>> def f1(lst):
...  return list(lst)
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
              3 SLICE+0             
              4 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

From [dis docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html):

> **SLICE+0()**
>   Implements TOS = TOS[:].

(TOS - top of stack)

> **CALL_FUNCTION(argc)**
>   Calls a function. The low byte of argc indicates
>   the number of positional parameters, the high byte the number of
>   keyword parameters. On the stack, the opcode finds the keyword
>   parameters first. For each keyword argument, the value is on top of
>   the key. Below the keyword parameters, the positional parameters are
>   on the stack, with the right-most parameter on top. Below the
>   parameters, the function object to call is on the stack. Pops all
>   function arguments, and the function itself off the stack, and pushes
>   the return value.