# Why list `my_list+['foo']` faster than `new_list = list(my_list); new_list.append('foo')` in Python?

Tags: python, performance, list

I stumbled into something that surprised me while writing some Python code. I was considering two ways of duplicating a list, then adding one more element to the duplicate:

```
# I thought this would be clean-looking but slow since it creates an extra one element list, ['foo']
mylist = range(4)
newlist_0 = mylist + ['foo']
print newlist_0 # [0, 1, 2, 3, 'foo']

# I thought this would be faster
newlist_1 = list(mylist)
newlist_1.append('foo')
print newlist_1 # [0, 1, 2, 3, 'foo']
```

Surprisingly the first way is not only nice to look at but also faster. I ran:

```
import timeit
for stmt in ['newlist_0 = mylist + ["foo"]', 'newlist_1 = list(mylist); newlist_1.append("foo")']:
    print "For statement {:50} timeit results are {}".format(stmt, timeit.repeat(setup='mylist = range(4)', stmt=stmt))
```

and got this output:

```
For statement newlist_0 = mylist + ["foo"]                       timeit results are [0.29012012481689453, 0.3021109104156494, 0.32175779342651367]
For statement newlist_1 = list(mylist); newlist_1.append("foo")  timeit results are [0.39945101737976074, 0.39692091941833496, 0.38529205322265625]
```

Momentarily I stumbled onto [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796138/why-is-copying-a-list-using-a-slice-faster-than-using-the-obvious-way) discussing the fact that `list(lst)` is slower than `lst[:]` for copying a list, but switching to using `[:]` to copy mylist doesn't change anything.

Comment: function call overhead

Comment: @wim, would I be right to infer, then, that neither `+` nor `["foo"]` involve function calls under the hood, but `append` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the disassembly. Your first method looks like this in Python 2.7 bytecode:

```
          0 LOAD_FAST                0 (mylist)
          3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
          6 BUILD_LIST               1
          9 BINARY_ADD
```

The second method looks like this:

```
          0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
          3 LOAD_FAST                0 (mylist)
          6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
          9 STORE_FAST               1 (newlist_1)

         12 LOAD_FAST                1 (newlist_1)
         15 LOAD_ATTR                1 (append)
         18 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
         21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
```

A few things that would make the latter slower based on a comparison of the disassembly:

1. `list` must be loaded from the globals namespace.
2. `append` must be loaded from the list object.
3. You pay for two call overheads rather than one.

The short answer is that Python byte code has very concise and efficient ways of storing short lists like `['foo']` and doing binary operations.

Comment: What are you using to get your disassembly? If I run `def f1(): newlist_0 = mylist + ['foo']` and then `dis.dis(f1)` I get seven lines of output and can't get it down to four by messing with the function.

Comment: I used the `dis` module and wrapped things in functions. My `f1` differs in that I `return mylist + ['foo']`.